# Is there a library in python which can validate fields so that I won't need to write my own regex or to create Form instance?

Tags: python, validation, python-2.7, flask

I'm building a simple web app using python and Flask. I'm adding a simple form and trying to avoid using all these Form instances; I want to validate client-side and server-side separately and to avoid understanding this whole Form classes thing that appears in Django and Flask tutorials, which always explain how to implement it but never explain what the idea behind it.

So once the form is posted, all I need to validate is that the username, for example, doesn't contain injections or specialchars before I save it. I need an `is_valid_username()` function that will save me time writing regex.

Is there such library?

Comment: This is basically the same question as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192747/recommendation-for-python-form-validation-library), and that question was also closed. These sort of "recommend a library to me" questions aren't what StackOverflow was designed for. You might do better asking this kind of question in IRCs, forums or mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try WTForms its good it should most prob. work

```
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, TextField, validators

class RegistrationForm(Form):
username     = TextField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
email        = TextField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
accept_rules = BooleanField('I accept the site rules', [validators.Required()])
```

To know complete visit http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/crash_course.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid Form instance... All I need is couple of boolean functions that validate classic cases: is_username_valid(), is_email_valid(). @user2291146